# Remote SSH Connection to MySQL not listening on port 3306

Tags: mysql, ssh, database-connection, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to connect Tableau to a SQL database that I have hosted on pythonanywhere.com, but it's not working and I believe the reason is that my remote connection to pythonanywhere.com has no process listening on port 3306.  In fact I think it's actively being killed, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Right now I'm on a Windows 10 Machine and I'm connecting through git bash in the following way:

```
 ssh -L 3306:jonathanbechtel.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306 jonathanbechtel@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
```

After I do this I run the command `netstat -an`  and see the following:

[image]

My understanding is that the `TIME_WAIT` status means that something locally killed the connection.

My understanding is that I need to have the local address `127.0.0.1:3306` to have a status of `LISTENING` in order for me to use the tunnel as a connection to anything else.

I've also connected to this database externally in a jupyter notebook, as well as through MySQL workbench, so I know it can be done in some capacity.

But I don't know why in this instance the connection is getting killed.

The command `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` says the connection worked:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that when I try to connect to my PuTTY connection (via Tableau) I get the following error message:

```
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Invalid username or password.

However, if I run the following python code, I can connect:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
 ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
 ssh_username=info['username'], ssh_password=info['password'],
 remote_bind_address=(info['db_address'], 3306)
) as tunnel:
  connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user=info['username'], password=info['db_password'],
    host=info['ssh_address'], port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
    database=info['db_name'],
)
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM classes', connection)
connection.close()
```

Comment: Your netstat output looks normal. What actual problem are you having?

Comment: Just to add to the above -- what is the actual error you're getting from the program that's trying to connect to your database on 127.0.0.1:3306?

Comment: @GilesThomas -- It's saying [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'jonathanbechtel'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Invalid username or password.  I know the obvious answer to this: check my password.  But in my case I have a notebook that runs python code and connects to the database just fine, but I get this error message when I try and connect to something via PuTTY.

Comment: And you're definitely using the DB password in Tableau, not the one you use to log in to the PythonAnywhere website?

Comment: @GilesThomas - Yes.  For now I've set them to be the same, just to make sure I'm not confusing the two.  I know this is a bad idea in general, but I figured this would reduce the chance of an unforced error on my part and I'll switch it to something else once this gets resolved.